# What is the length of an empty 2d array in JS?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to evaluate if my 2d array

```
let lines=[[]]
```

is empty or not, so i checked `lines.length==0`, which returned false. So I logged to console the length of lines, right after it was defined and it returned 1. I'm wondering if there is any way to differentiate between lines in it's empty state and when it only contains one array.

I tried logging the size of an empty 2d array (`[[]]`) which is one, and one with some data in the first array (`[[1,2,3,4]]`), both of which return one.

Comment: You're working with single dimensional arrays. Checking `length` on an array will always return 1 in your case because your first "level" array as you wish contains a value that is another array.

Comment: You can use `lines.filter(child => child.length).length` to ignore empty arrays.

Comment: What exactly did you expect? Are you looking for the sum of all length? The length of the first item?

Comment: Can I check if lines is empty by checking if lines[0] equals [] then?

Comment: @devor No, because two identical arrays are not equal (unless they are references to the *same* array). For example, `console.log([] == []) //false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty matrix should really be represented by a simple `[]`. To also detect the case you mentioned (i.e. `[[]]`), you would do:

```
if (lines.length === 0 || lines[0].length === 0)
```

But `[[]]` really is saying you have a matrix with one row and no columns, which is counter-intuitive. An empty matrix has *no* rows, and nothing more need to be said, so `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (lines.flat().length === 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`lines` is an array with a single element, an empty array.

If you wanted to check that no element in `lines` is a populated array, you could check via an `every` predicate:

```
lines.every(elem=>!elem.length)
```

This would check that every element of `lines` has a falsey value for `length`. More rigorously, you might do

```
lines.every(elem=>elem instanceof Array && elem.length===0)
```

to check that every element of `lines` is an `Array` that has a `length` of `0`.